# Add Identity key to Sub Class in ravenDB

Tags: ravendb

I have this two class :

```
public class BlogPost
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime PublishedAt { get; set; }
    public string[] Tags { get; set; }
    public BlogComment[] Comments { get; set; }
}

public class BlogComment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

and add to documents like this :

```
// Creating a new instance of the BlogPost class
BlogPost post = new BlogPost()
                    {
                        Title = "Hello RavenDB",
                        Category = "RavenDB",
                        Content = "This is a blog about RavenDB",
                        Comments = new BlogComment[]
                                    {
                                        new BlogComment() {Title = "Unrealistic", Content = "This example is unrealistic"},
                                        new BlogComment() {Title = "Nice", Content = "This example is nice"}
                                    }
                    };
```

is there a way that my comments have Identity key like my **BlogPost** class?

and another question:
is there a way that get comment object without using post. something like this :

```
using( var session = doc.OpenSession() )
{
    return session.Load<BlogComment>( ID );
}
```

or

```
using( var session = doc.OpenSession() )
{
     return ( from comment in session.Query<BlogComment>()
     where comment.Title == title
     select comment ).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just have an integer property on BlogPost, increment that and set that value whenever you add a new comment. That would give you identity style ids within the scope of the post.